# Is it possible to get +790 in under 48 hours, or is this a glitch?

Tags: bug, status-planned

I'm curious... Mr Skeet is heading up the May [league tables](http://stackexchange.com/leagues/52/month/programmers). No problem with that, but a rep increase of +790 in under 2 days seems to be a mathematical impossibility, given he has no accepted answers on Programmers.

Is this a glitch or is there some way of getting around the +200 daily cap (other than bounty points)?

Comment: Crikey! Sure is a lot of rep... :)

Comment: Not any more he isn't :D Problem solved.

Answer (score 8):

Both the rep leagues on Stack Exchange and on individual sites see rep changes as occurring *right now*, instead of *when they actually did happen*.

Normally, this is fine: you get upvoted, your rep increases, the leagues take note.  With migration, we move all the post's votes over with their original creation dates, and when we increment the owner's rep with that lump sum, the leagues **incorrectly see this increase as happening for today**.

We've got a fix planned for this, but it will be a few weeks until we can get it implemented.

Answer (score 6):

[This question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/72806/how-do-you-make-people-accept-code-review) was migrated from Stack Overflow yesterday (1st May 2011). It has an answer from Jon that is quite highly upvoted.

If you check [Jon's reputation graph](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/8958/jon-skeet?tab=reputation#reppage_1-repview_graph) you can see a spike on Friday August 29th 2009 *when the question was originally answered* that must have included a bounty.

This must be the source of the increase.

Jon's reputation *on this site* has increased dramatically over the last 24 hours as a result even though the reputation was first awarded nearly 2 years ago. I'd suggest it's an edge case that we'll have to live with.

Comment: So does this mean the rep from old votes doesn't transfer, but bounties do?  I think that's fair, if so, but I'd like to know for sure.  I really don't think it's fair if the rep from votes transfers, though.

Comment: @Renesis - I think the rep from old posts *does* transfer now, but that's only based on a slight increase to my rep on Server Fault that I couldn't explain otherwise.

Comment: @ChrisF - That's disappointing.  Soon the leaders of Programmers will be users who've never really been active on the site (from old, legendary SO answers).

Comment: @Renesis - only if the questions keep getting migrated. I'm very vocal on MSO that old questions **shouldn't** be migrated. The issue of rep distortion has been brought up and this is a good example to use.

Comment: I used to think some old questions should be migrated, but given this issue, I'm in your camp.

Comment: Personally I feel that rep should stay where it was awarded and tend to agree that old questions shouldn't be migrated.